# Calculando integrais numéricas a partir de arrays do numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Eu tenho a integral tripla da figura. Eu usei a documentação do `scipy` para resolver ela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu quero trocar os valores dos limites superiores de x, y e z, que nesse problema são os valores 2, 3 e 2 por arrays.

Tipo onde for 2 (x) eu quero um numpy array `[2,3,4,5]`, onde for o valor 3 (y) eu quero o `np.array [5,6,7,8]` e onde for 2 (z) eu quero o `np.array [0,1,2,3]`.

Como eu faço essa substituição?

Abaixo segue o meu código:

```
from scipy import integrate
f = lambda z, y, x: (12*x)*(y**2)*(z**3)
a = integrate.tplquad(f, -1, 2, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3,
                  lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: 2)


b = np.array([2,3,4,5])
c = np.array([5,6,7,8])
d = np.array([0,1,2,3])

g = integrate.tplquad(f, -1, b, lambda x: 0, lambda x: c,
                  lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: d)
```

Comment: O nquad serve?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente encapsular seu código em uma função separada que recebe a lista de limites por parâmetro:

```py
def calcular_integrais_triplas(f, limites):
    resultados = []

    for limite in limites:
        (r, _) = integrate.tplquad(f, *limite)
        resultados.append(r)

    return resultados
```

Daí abaixo disso você cria a função que quer integrar e a lista de limites:

```py
f = lambda x, y, z: 12*x*(y*y)*(z*z*z)

limites = [
    (0, 2, 0, 3, -1, 2),
    (0, 3, 0, 3, -1, 2),
    (0, 4, 0, 3, -1, 2),
    (0, 5, 0, 3, -1, 2),
]
```

Perceba que cada linha da lista de limites é uma tupla que contém os limites exatamente na ordem que a função `integrate.tplquad` precisa.

Feito isso, é só chamar a sua nova função e você receberá de volta uma lista com os respectivos resultados:

```py
resultados = calcular_integrais_triplas(f, limites)

print(*resultados, sep='\n')
```

O programa printa o seguinte no terminal:

```
648.0000000000001
3280.5
10368.000000000002
25312.5
```

Que são justamente os resultados da sua integral usando os limites especificados na lista de limites.